# My motorbikes front fork oil is leaking and making a noise in brakes

Tags: motorcycle, oil-leak, forks

I am from Bangalore! I own a pulsar 200ns and my bike has a bent fork. Due this the bike's fork oil started leaking. I got the forks done but it's still leaking. What should I do?? Is it OK??? Do I have to visit my mechanic? Basically my front brakes while applied don't hold much and make a squeaking sound.

Comment: pleaseusepunctuationifyoudoitwillbeeasiertounderstandyourquestion

Answer (score 3):

If you had the "forks done" then take it back to whoever rebuilt your fork and let them know that it leaks now. If a rebuild was not performed on the fork, it now should be. If you're getting fork oil on your break rotors, that is a very serious issue and will cause squeaking and loss of friction.

Answer (score 2):

The fork seals are leaking due to the bent fork tubes. Firstly these require straightening which is a specialist job. 
If the fork tubes are not perfectly straight and smooth the seals will always leak.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean when you say, "I got the forks done"?

A bent fork stanchion should be replaced. Some places can straighten forks, but it needs to be a very subtle bend. Straightening can also weaken the fork. The cost to do this is roughly the same as a used replacement, so replacement is preferable.

If you put new fork seals on a bent fork they won't hold oil. Stanchions are percision parts, and fork seals form a very tight seal around the stanchion. A bend will cause enough of a gap during the stroke that oil will leak.

As for the braking issue, it could be any number of things. My first guess would be that fork oil has leaked onto your brake pads or disc, and they're no longer generating the same amount of friction. Try cleaning your disc with brake cleaner. If that doesn't help, you'll need to replace your pads. You can try shaving some friction material off of them, but oil will soak into them fairly quickly, and you may not be able to salvage them.

Answer (score 1):

- Fork oil leak: As suggested by others, it seems to be a fork oil seal issue. Make sure that when you take your bike to the Bajaj service station next time, the mechanics do the job right, in front of you. Bajaj after sales service is known to be filled with issues. Get the fork bend removed properly, followed by fixing the fork oil seal.
- Brakes gone bad: Check your brake oil reservoir for brake fluid level and  check your brake pads. Bangalore being a dusty city, accumulation of dust could also result in the squeaky noise/sound that you have mentioned.

The fork oil leakage issue has to be fixed immediately. It's better if you do not ride it for lengthier duration. If you continue to ride with the current situation, your fork oil will keep leaking until there is very little oil left in the fork, resulting in a mishap.

Answer (score 0):

Your forks are leaking due to a seal failure.
Either they are still way too damaged and the seal isn't working or after you straightened them up you reused the old seals that were already damaged.

You MUST visit a SPECIALIST to service (or even replace) your forks and clean your brakes (rotors calipers etc) from leaked oil. It is EXTREMELY dangerous to ride your bike in this condition.

Answer (score 0):

A bent fork will easily break the oil seal, and cause the oil to leak. 
It will also affect balancing, more on higher speeds.
Instead of trying to fix it, you should ideally change it.

For the brakes, if there's oil on the rotor, get it cleaned.
The brakes could also be squeaking because the pads are worn out or there's dirt build up on it.

Depending on how old the bike is, the disk braking assembly can also become weak.